# Why is the magnetization inside a diamagnetic material antiparallel to the external field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, dipole

Let's say I have a constant magnetic field and I dive into it a diamagnetic material. Griffiths says that in the presence of a magnetic field, matter becomes magnetized and it will be found to contain many tiny dipoles with a net alignment along some direction.

However, what's exactly the link between the alignment of those dipole and the way that the external magnetic field induces a current to the atoms which produces a magnetic field in the opposite direction (Lenz's law).

How exactly the magnetic field aligns those dipoles and what exactly are the loops of those dipoles, are they the "path" of electrons?

I think those 2 questions is what I'm missing to fully understand the link between the 2 statements if there is a link.